# How to make a ScrollBar in a Grid?

Tags: visual-foxpro

How to make a ScrollBar in a Grid?

It is Vertical Scrollbar. What possible codes and where should I put the codes, in the form.int or in the grid. . . . ?

Comment: Can you give some more details??

Answer (score 1):

Set the Scrollbars property to 2 in the Property Sheet.